# Mocking an Object Within an Object

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

I have started learning Rhino Mocks and have been able to follow the examples in the online wiki. I thought I would apply those learnings to a home project of mine and came unstuck after hours of fighting against the technology. Here is what I am trying to do (if I don’t provide enough info, please let me know – I don’t want to just do a huge code dump):

I have a class called **DataSurface**.

It has a member called **unitOfWork**, which in turn contains three repositories **TaskRepository**, **WorkRepository** and **ProjectRepository**. Each are exposed as Getter properties.

In DataSurface, there is an **InsertNewWorkItem** method which calls the Find method on the **TaskRepository** as follows:

```cs
public void InsertNewWorkItem(Entities.Work workItem)
{
    var taskForWorkItem = this.unitOfWork.TaskRepositoryInstance.Find(t => t.ID == workItem.TaskId).First();

    Work newWorkItem = new Work
    {
       DateOfWork = workItem.DateOfWork,
       Description = workItem.Description,
       Duration = workItem.Duration,           
       Task1 = taskForWorkItem,
       Week = workItem.WeekNumber,
    };

        this.unitOfWork.WorkRepositoryInstance.Add(newWorkItem);
        this.unitOfWork.WorkRepositoryInstance.SaveChanges();
}
```

What I was hoping to verify is that the **Find** method of the **TaskRepository** was called.

Because the repository is “2 classes deep” i.e. a member inside a member vis a vis the **InsertNewWorkItem** method, I could not seem to create the repository mock objects at all.

I feel that what I am trying to do is an anti-pattern.

I also realise that perhaps the code is not mockable, as is. I tried every combination of instantiating the repositories inside the unitofwork (e.g. constructor DI), but every time, Rhino Mocks threw errors.

Are there any testing experts out there who can set me straight.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to abstract all classes by interfaces then you would be able mocking anything, and yes you can mock N-levels deep.

BTW, do you inject somehow `unitOfWork` into the `DataStructure` class or instantiate it in the class explicitly? To be  able mocking it you need to inject it into, generally this is rule of thumb - injecting dependencies and not instantiatign it in a class.

Comment: This is the part where I don't think the code is Mockable. I don't want the repositories to implement their own interfaces. They inherit from an abstract class: 
    GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
I don't want each repository to also inherit from another interface which adds further specialization methods. Then, you start getting into wildy unmanageable code with interfaces flying everywhere.

Comment: Let me guess - instead of having business-specific methods with descriptive names you expose `IQueryable` everywhere as "manageable" code?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I've been asked to call you a knob. Don't know what that means, am just helping out the OP.

Comment: I don't understand the comment from hg lim. How random.